# Issue with Visual Studio authentication for SharePoint app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint

I am working on a SharePoint app in visual studio and am running into issues when attempting to debug.

I press start and as expected the Connect to SharePoint window pops up asking me for my credentials. I enter them and attempt to proceed but instead of continuing to the debug site it goes to the root web of the site in the Connect to SharePoint window and freezes.

What could be causing this? What can I do to resolve it?

Edit: It was working ~two weeks ago when I last worked on this project but since I came back to it yesterday it won't let me debug.

[image: Screenshot of Authentication error]

Comment: Check the debug site url again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the Office 365 authentication through VS. The server which controls our domain had been down for a few days the previous week and when it was brought back up the clock was running a few hours wrong. I took my computer off the domain and it authenticated fine.